# Python Base64 encoding Vs Java Base64 encoding

Tags: java, python, base64

Following is my python code to generate base64 encoded string:

```
base64str = base64.encodestring('%s:' % getpass.getuser())
```

I want same base64str using Java. Here is my Java code snippet:

```
String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
byte[] encoded_str = Base64.encodeBase64(user.getBytes());
String encoded_string = new String(encoded_str).trim();
```

Somehow python encoded string is different than Java. I'm using "import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;" library.

Any idea ?

Comment: How to ask for help: don't say, "they are different," show the two different values.  There are clues there...

Comment: As a side note, don't try to tag your question with as many tags as possible. Someone who's an expert in HTTP or Apache wouldn't be able to help you here, so there's no reason to use those tags. Just java, python, and base64 is all you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python code appends a colon to the input String before calling Base64

```
>>> print '%s:' % 'test'
test:
```

When I add the colon to your java code, I am able to get the same result in my testing (python and Java),

```
String user = System.getProperty("user.name") + ":";
byte[] encoded_str = Base64.encodeBase64(user
    .getBytes());
String encoded_string = new String(encoded_str)
    .trim();
System.out.println(encoded_string);
```

Comment: So this whole question is a simple typo.

Comment: @abarnert It's a little more subtle then a normal typo (because it's a String format issue), but you might certainly be of that opinion.

Comment: Thanks Elliott ! Python code owner is someone else and it didn't make any sense to include ":" after "%s". So it is not issue of typo but bad code practice.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) in Java doesn't guarantee the character set used. Use [`String.getBytes(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) instead to always be sure that you get the encoding you want.

```
user.getBytes("UTF-8")
```